# Manage empty item in item_list theme

Tags: 7, theming

Imagine this simple

```
 $items = array(
   'string',
   'string2',
   $extra_items,
 );
```

And theme a block content like

```
 $content = array(
   'subject'   => t('Block title'),
   'content'   => array(
     '#theme'  => 'item_list',
     '#items'  => $items,
     '#attributes' => array('class' => 'my-UL'),
   ),
 );
```

`$extra_items` is getting values from a custom hook that may be empty!In that case
theme_item_list() brings an empty `<li></li>` for that item that is `NULL`

How can i ensure that this `<li></li>` is displayed only when this item has a value?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why can't you run `array_filter` or similar on `$items` ?

Comment: I could try that, but it seems weird that [theme_item_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) doesn't take care of that..

Comment: @AliceHeaton array_filter() worked perfectly, if you convert your comment to an answer i 'd be happy to accept it, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to run [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on `$items` - this will remove the empty entries.

Whether this should be handled by [theme_item_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) or not is debatable. It doesn't make semantic sense to theme empty list items - however in most cases the filtering would not be necessary, so from a performance point of view it doesn't make sense for [theme_item_list](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) to do it.